# How to avoid deployment at each reboot JBoss EAP 7.2 server?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Every time I start jboss EAP 7.2.0 server (standalone), my ear file present in the "standalone\deployments" folder is deployed. Is it possible to avoid deployment at each reboot of the server?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/configuration_guide/reference_material#reference_deploy_scanner_marker_files)

So `earfilename.ear.skipdeploy` should do the trick.

Also if you undeploy the application a `earfilename.ear.undeployed` file is created. As long as this file exists the application won't be deployed.